# And now I'm sitting in my Frozen Chamber

Tags: riddle

Many have seen my crown,
but none have seen my throne.
I have hundreds in my harem,
but none of them is my own.

My people work from sunrise to sunset,
just as I commanded.
And sometime I just sit on the roof
and watch where the dandelions landed.

Comment: Is the answer one of the [Mughal rulers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mughal_emperors)?

Comment: @ABcDexter nope ABcDexter

Comment: "My people works" instead of "My people work". Intentional or typo?

Comment: Also "Many has" instead of "Many have"? Intentional or typo?

Comment: @Duncan all these grammar errors XD

Comment: If @Munir is correct then the last line should be "and watch where the dandelions **come from**. as that is the way **<retracted/>** face

Comment: @DarcyThomas oh is that the case?  I always thought the rooster face toward where the wind blows to, not from

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it is

> A rooster

Many has seen my crown, but none have seen my throne.

> A rooster has a crown on it's head, but no throne

I have hundreds in my harem, but none of them is my own.

> All the hens in the "harem" belong to the farmer, not the rooster.

My people work from sunrise to sunset, just as I commanded.

> The rooster crowing at sunrise used to be the alarm for the people to wake up and start working.

And sometime I just sit on the roof and watch where the dandelions landed.

> Weather vanes on the top of barn roofs are sometimes shaped like a rooster. They point in direction of wind, and the dandelions will land in the direction of wind. So they see the dandelions land.

And now I'm sitting in my Frozen Chamber

> The rooster is culled and put in a freezer.

Comment: Also the dandelions line works because it points towards the direction of the wind

Comment: @gannolloy that was my thought too...i will clarify in the answer

Comment: Nicely done!  This is the correct answer

Comment: "And now I'm sitting in my Frozen Chamber" could mean he's now been culled and put in the freezer

Comment: 1 point for gryffindor!  ...I mean for Paul Evans!

Comment: @PaulEvans I would suggest this as an edit if Munir doesn't add it pretty soon.

Comment: @jpmc26 Good prod, as I was editing Munir rose to the occasion :) )