# Gold fish for breakfast

Tags: riddle

> Six little fish in a goldfish bowl
>   Swimming in a golden shoal.
>   Fry the fish, and when they're done
>   Six little fish are turned to one.

Assuming I'm not eating my daughter's goldfish, what am I eating?

Comment: What are we supposed to find? is the question self included in the riddle?

Comment: Strangely, this is not tagged enigmatic-puzzles.

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Hm.  Do riddles need an explicit question?  I'm looking at [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/31294/21402) for comparison.  Does adding "What is this?" change anything?

Comment: I think this can be reopened now...OP has added what he wants us to do.

Comment: You're eating microfiche that melt and become one!

Comment: Alternative answer: nuking a box of Peeps in the warm glow of the microwave until they form a megaPeep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

> You're eating an omelette.

Because

> The "gold fish" represent the golden yolks of eggs. They "swim" around in the egg whites. In the process of making an omelette (using a frying pan), these yolks will be broken down and mixed together, creating a single delicious mass of yellow egg.

Answer (score 2):

> Did you turn them into a fish cake? The stuff where you get all the meat. Mince it and add various ingredients before pan frying it?

Answer (score 0):

My thought !

> Little goldfishes eat each other until one is remaining...!

Fry the fish, and when they're done

> They were young and they're done means they have grown/eaten.[fry : the young of various species of fish!!]